# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web-hosting

Hi I have developed an ASP.Net MVC 3.0 application using VS 2010 and hosted the same in a server using IIS. I am getting the following error while running trying to access the application using hosted url.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows update caused MVC3 and MVC4 stop working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393157/windows-update-caused-mvc3-and-mvc4-stop-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install MVC on the server or add the MVC DLL's to the bin folder of the app

Comment: Yeahh... It worked. The dll which I added to the bin folder was different version. I updated with the correct version and it worked. Thanks.