# Getting "The type name or alias FooController could not be resolved" on different server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

Does anyone have any tips on how I might track down the root cause of this error:

> The type name or alias FooController could not be resolved

I have an ASP.net MVC web application using Unity. My application runs fine locally. However, when I publish the site to a remote server, I get the error above.

I tried on two different remote servers and got the same error. However, when I published the site to a different directory on my local dev box, it works just fine. So, I copied the local working copy to the remote server(s). I get the same exact error. I re-arranged the order of the controllers in the Unity config file and the error will always show the first controller in the file. That is, if I move the type registration for BarController above FooController, the error will show:

> The type name or alias BarController could not be resolved

So it appears that anytime a controller is encountered in the Unity configuration file, it fails, but only on the remote servers. It problem doesn't seam to be tied to a specified controller.

Therefore, it seams the problem is environmental. Perhaps the remote servers are missing something in the GAC, that I have on my local dev box. I ran though the references and didn't see anything new added since our last release, but I could be missing something.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can track down the root cause of this problem? The error message doesn't tell me much. I need to know **why** the FooController could not be resolved.

Comment: If you can't debug, at least look in event log - error loading types are usually show up there.

Comment: All the DLL's are in the bin folder?  Are your controllers defined in the same project as the web application?

Comment: The event log shows pretty much the same information on the error page. The controllers are in the same project and I verified the DLLs are in the bin.

Comment: Could you post the unity configuration code and the composition root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I setup a development environment on one of the remote servers. I noticed a problem with one of the references in the web project. The MVC assembly needed to be fixed. So I removed and re-added it. Worked like a charm.

Looking at the change this made, here's what I saw:

[image]

The code on the left is my local dev box. It was referencing version 3.0.0.1 and the code on the right is after I fixed the reference on the remote server. It is referencing version 3.0.0.0.

It seams my local dev box had some strange version of ASP.net MVC installed. So I uninstalled it, and reinstalled from the latest published version and republished the code from the local dev build and it worked fine.

After look into this even further, this appears to be the root cause of the problem to begin with:

[Windows update caused MVC3 and MVC4 stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393157/windows-update-caused-mvc3-and-mvc4-stop-working)