# What do I need to install on a build server for MVC 3 & 4

Tags: model-view-controller, msbuild

I'm building a build slave for Jenkins with Ant and Ivy to build our Windows application. Parts of the application use MVC3 and MVC4. The same solution builds fine on my development PC. I cannot change the build, sln or csproj files to make this work.

I **don't** want to install Visual Studio at all.

What should I install to get this working?

Here's what I have already installed which does **not** work:

- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2 - VWD Express 2010 Tools
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 2
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4 Runtime
- Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4
- Microsoft Build Tools 2013
- Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.4 - Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web
- Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 - Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web

Here are the errors I'm seeing from the MSBuild steps:

```
[exec] Controllers\Controller1.cs(547,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [xxx.csproj]
[exec] Controllers\Controller1.cs(547,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPostAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [xxx.csproj]
[exec] Controllers\Controller2.cs(21,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPost' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [xxx.csproj]
[exec] Controllers\Controller2.cs(21,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpPostAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [xxx.csproj]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the wasted question. Had I looked earlier in the log, I would have seen that.

It turns out this is the known issue of the MVC 3.0.0.0 versus 3.0.0.1 reference caused by a Microsoft security patch.

```
"C:\scm\opt\hg\main\core\F4I\Reporting\Foundation\Poiesis.Foundation.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\scm\opt\hg\main\core\F4I\Reporting\Foundation\Security\SSO\Poiesis.ClinicalModel.Security.Web.SSO.csproj" (default target) (16) ->
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\scm\opt\hg\main\core\F4I\Reporting\Foundation\Security\SSO\Poiesis.ClinicalModel.Security.Web.SSO.csproj]
```

[Windows update caused MVC3 and MVC4 stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393157/windows-update-caused-mvc3-and-mvc4-stop-working)