# How to resolve? Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

With reference to [questions/26393157/windows-update-caused-mvc3-and-mvc4-stop-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393157/windows-update-caused-mvc3-and-mvc4-stop-working/). The quickest way to resolve the warning below?

> Assuming assembly reference 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' matches
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35', you may need to supply runtime
>   policy.

Comment: I had the same problem recently and finally solved it, check [my solution on stackoverlow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125730/razor-views-show-warnings-cs1702-after-upgrading-to-microsoft-aspnet-mvc-version)

Answer (score 17):

I've had this happen with my NuGet packages every once in a while. I haven't been able to identify exactly how it happens. (I assume user error.)
I didn't need to upgrade anything to solve it, just clear the NuGet cache:

I use the nuget command line tool found [here](https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/latest/nuget.exe).

You can clear all caches with this command:

```
nuget locals all -clear
```

See: https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference

You'll probably need to restart Visual Studio if it is open.

Comment: In my case I also had to restart Visual Studio to get rid of those messages

Comment: This is the best answer to the question if you are seeing this error popup "out of the blue" on established solutions.

Comment: If you don't have NuGet installed independently: `dotnet nuget locals all --clear`

Answer (score 10):

As per the best answer to the question....

- Update MVC package (Visual Studio > Right click project/solution > manage nuget packages > Updates > Microsoft ASP.NET MVC > Update)
- Manually add the compilation assembly

but then

- Find - System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0
- and replace with - System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1

Which will find all the hidden references in the Views/Web.config files.

Comment: what do you mean "update MVC package"? it wil require a lot of tests... is it possible do not update it and fix the problem?

Comment: If there is a desire to update: then updating the package doesn't for some reason update the web.config files, which caused me a problem. Hence the additional step of find/replace.

Comment: @SimonLegg  I updated all packages and restarted, it works fine.

Comment: @ARUNEdathadan - In that case my issue could have been something else - maybe clearing NuGet cache as per Brian Merrel's answer might of solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time I have had this issue I always start by doing a rebuild which will clear your bin folder. You likely do not need to close and open visual studio, as I never have, and it should work.

If this doesn't work then try more complicated solutions like those above but this could be a quick, clean fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this warning in RoslynPad because one of the dll's I was referencing (for me it was mscorlib.dll) used a different version than the retrieved version via NuGet. As the warning states, you can solve it with solve it with a runtime policy with a link to the dll of the version you want to be using. Just add something like this to the top of your file:

```
#r "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply but in my case this warning was showing up because I was using **different versions of Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc** across my Visual Studio solution. I was able to get rid of it by upgrading the older packages to the same version.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me after trying severally is to update application insights and all packages from NuGet. Then I ensured that there were no version conflicts on the App insights and it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Don't refer NuGet Package Components and interfaces directly from your cshtml code. Instead, write your own components, extesion methods and view models referencing them from plain C# code placed in cs files. First, then you wouldn't obtain CS1702 warning. And secondly, this will facilitate future migrations to newer versions of the NuGet package or even another package: All necessary fixes will be shown you by the compiler.

This is probably the desired change in your run-time policy.

Answer (score -2):

After tested all propositions, I finally succeeded to get rid of the warning by editing the .csproj of my web application and set the property **MvcBuildViews** to false.

Maybe this could help some of you.

Comment: MvcBuildViews = true helps catch errors at compile time instead of runtime. Setting it to false simply means your views aren't type checked and any errors won't show up until runtime.